# TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations' of undefined in Google Translate API

Tags: python, google-translate, google-api-python-client

I use the following code from this [Google Translate API's Get Started](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started)

```
  <head>
    <title>Translate API Example</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
  <div id="translation"></div>
  <script>
  function translateText(response) {
    // ERROR SHOW HERE
    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
  </script>
  <script>
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);

    var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
    newScript.src = source;

    // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
  </script>
</body>
```

And I get the error **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations' of undefined"**

Please tell me how to fix this error,

Thanks,

Comment: Did you provide an API key?

Answer (score 0):

I received the message from someone who **tell me how to fix this error**,

> I think I was able to replicate your error, but only once - the example works for me, in a variety of translated languages and so on. I thought I saw the error just once, before I had my Chrome developer console running. I did try adding console.log(response) to the translateText() callback, but that also has not shown the bug again. Try seeing what you can log at // ERROR SHOW HERE in your sample.
>
> Of course, the example in the documentation is extremely brittle code — I can imagine there are circumstances where the data member isn't present, only an error. e.g.:

```
// API callback
translateText({
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "debugInfo": "Target language is not set to a valid language code:…\n"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
);
```

And, it's really good,

Need add "console.log(response)" as below code :

```
<script>
function translateText(response) {
console.log(response);
document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

}

Thanks,