# Has not supported to download Google Translate API library in Google App Engine's Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-translate, google-api-python-client

I can see in this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) which **has not supported to download Google Translate API library yet**.

Therefore, I want to ask **There is another method to use Google Translate API in Google App Engine or not?**

Please tell me,

Thanks,

p/s : This is the [link](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started) I followed, but it shows [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202888/typeerror-cannot-read-property-translations-of-undefined-in-google-translate)

Comment: $easy_install --user google-api-python-client use this commend..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's a known bug in the Quickstart tool where it doesn't work for APIs that don't use OAuth 2.0, a fix should be pushed this week.

In the mean time here is a translate sample from the client library:

[Translate Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/translate)

The `developerKey` in that code should be filled in with the API Key found in the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Comment: Yes, I found it ... And there are many ways to complete this task. Do you see the error, I fixed another way. Thanks,